# css to build a typical footer

Tags: css, web, frontend

What's the appropriate code to build a typical CSS footer as such. The box outline is simply for noting them as a unity, but not supposed to be shown as solid. A simple css framwork of building such structure would be appreciated!

[image]

a typical concrete application of it would be sth like this.

[image]

Comment: Is that so tough? `ul` `li` and `float`, that's all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer .row {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQpPw/

If you want more rows, then all you have to do is to change the HTML dom and increase the rows width. For 4 it would be width: 25% etc.

Comment: Is there a way of not using float? I used a combination of position:absolute and position:relative. Is that also viable of building this?

Comment: Why would you use position:absolute/relative? Float + %width are working on each resolution, try resizing the fiddle's content. Huge CSS frameworks (Twitter Bootstrap) are doing it the same way.

Comment: well. I was using position before. just wondering if it's possible to do it that way, nothing else. Since float gives better result. I will adopt float. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-content">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
        <li>link#1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
     width:960px;
     background-color:grey;
     height:400px;
 }
 .footer-content {
     width: 800px;
     padding-top:50px;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
 .footer-content ul {
     float:left;
     margin-right: 100px;
     list-style: none;
 }
```

See demo : http://jsfiddle.net/KDm9N/1/